# How can i fix vulerability in package dependancies

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, installation

I'm trying to learn javascript, and every tutorial I follow gives the same errors or more. I don't understand what any of this is or what it wants me to do. When I go to the url it doesn't fix anything. What do I need to do? Can someone help me with some background reading or something more simple? I know other programming languages, but I don't have any experience with this kind of thing.

```sh
found 1 low severity vulnerability in 3522 scanned packages 1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details. ➜ web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗ npx npm-force-resolutions npx: installed 5 in 1.27s ➜ web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗ npm install audited 3522 packages in 1.712s

2 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details ➜ web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗ npm fund js-starter-code@1.0.0 ├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/isaacs │ └── glob@7.1.6 └─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb └── resolve@1.15.1

➜ web-dev-starter git:(master) ✗
```

I don't know who these people or this git hub is. Do I have to join a membership to get the code? What is this?

Comment: I can't really read that; please consider formatting as the original (semi-)structured text. It's low-vulnerability anyway, and `npm fund` is for finding out how to give the package maintainers money. I might follow a different tutorial--none of the ones I (tend) to recommend have those errors.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry for the readability issue. I'm not sure how to format semi structured text, Sorry for my inexperience.  It's good the issue is not serious. I've tried a few different tutorials and they all give some kind of similar errors or many more.  Should i learn Fund or NPM or something else before learning javascript? Do i need to know terminal to write javascript? I have little experience with it

Comment: “Fund” means “provide money to”.

Comment: ok. should I ask how much they charge or make an offer?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is a very popular website used by developers to collaborate on projects. It is a place where you can upload your code, and other people can download it to their own machine, work on it, and suggest changes. If you want to join GitHub you can go to [github.com](https://github.com) and create an account for free.

There is a bunch of stuff to learn about using their site, particularily about the tool called `git`. This is a tool that helps you keep track of changes and updates you make to files in your project. I suggest starting at [GitHub's own resources](https://try.github.io/) if you want to learn `git`.

You don't need to do either to fix your vulnerabilities, though. Let's try to figure out what is going on.

When you are doing tutorials, you are probably given some boilerplate code (that is, some code that someone else wrote for you) that you have to download to your own computer. The first step in the tutorial is most likely telling you to do something like this in your Terminal:

```sh
$ cd path/to/project
$ npm install
```

Here, `npm` is [**Node package manager**](https://www.npmjs.com/). For our purposes, `npm` is a collection of software that you can download with your Terminal and then include in your code. For example, if you are writing an express application in JavaScript, you need to start your files with

```js
const express = require('express');
```

JavaScript knows about `express` (or `react` or whatever software you are using) because `npm` installed them for you when you ran `npm install`. When you call this command, `npm` looks in the file called `package.json` and installs the software listed there.

Sometimes, there may be a vulnerability detected in one of the pieces of software `npm` installs; maybe there is something about it that opens your application up for malicious attacks or workarounds if your software goes live on the internet. When these are discovered and registered, `npm` will tell you about them.

Note that if you are not using your application on anything that is going to be used by others, you don't really have to worry about these vulnerabilites. But if you want to fix them, you can write

```sh
$ npm audit fix
```

into your Terminal, and let `npm` take care of it for you. Then `npm` will try to upgrade the affected software to a newer version where the vulnerability has been fixed.

As a final sidenote, even though you are maybe only using one or two pieces of software from `npm`, you may note that it is installing a lot more than that. This is because a lot of the software kept by `npm` depends on *other* software from `npm`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to read up on all this and hopefully be able to understand enough to try to learn JavaScript. It is really overwhelming